# android:targetSdkVersion="23" causing input error

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

When using **cocos2d-x 3.6**, I set the `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it will cause problem for some input methods(such as **POBox、iWnn IME**) that the confirmation of input in them become newline and they cannot finish the input. Is there anybody face this problem too, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you update your project (cocos2d-x 3.6 that released in first quarter of 2015). It's long time, lots of improvement and new API added in FrameWork.

If your target sdk version is 23, causing issue due to permissions request, building with high level API can not make sure run on low API devices. And especially is that, Android NDK break compatibility since API 21.

so in my suggestion you should target `android-13`. Android 3.2 (HONEYCOMB_MR2) your App/game covers most of devices.